# A function to conduct a shapiro test on multiple variables at once

Tags: r, function, functional-programming

I have data frames similar to `dat1` created below:

```r
dat1 <- data.frame(Region = rep(c("r1","r2"), each = 100),
                   State = rep(c("NY","MA","FL","GA"), each = 10),
                   Loc = rep(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"),each = 5),
                   ID = rep(c(1:10), each=2),
                   var1 = rnorm(200),
                   var2 = rnorm(200),
                   var3 = rnorm(200),
                   var4 = rnorm(200),
                   var5 = rnorm(200))
```

I am trying to make a function that allows me to specify the data, grouping variable (`Region`,`State`,or `Loc`), and variable columns (e.g., `var1:var5`). I want to specify the `var` columns to include as column numbers associated with whatever data frame I specify (so here if I wanted to do all 5 `var`s, the argument would be given `5:9`). I want the function to conduct univariate shapiro tests `shapiro_test()` from the `rstatix` package and return the variable and grouping variable name when the .
As of now, my function looks like this which mostly mirrors the workflow I use to do this job outside of a function:

```r
library(rstatix)
UnivShapiro <- function(dat, groupvar, columns){
  var.list <- paste(names(dat[columns]),collapse=",")
  result<-
    dat%>%
    group_by(paste(groupvar))%>%
    shapiro_test(vars=paste(var.list))%>%
    arrange(variable)%>%
    dplyr::filter(p<0.05)
  result
}
```

I have tried several different variations of this, but when I try to run the function: `UnivShapiro(dat=dat1, groupvar="Region", columns = 5:9)`, I get an error saying:  `Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist. x The column var1,var2,var3,var4,var5 doesn't exist.` I cant figure out whats going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables are evaluated differently within the function. This would be one way to get the desired results (used p<0.5 for illustration purposes):

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
set.seed(1)
dat1 <- data.frame(Region = rep(c("r1","r2"), each = 100),
                   State = rep(c("NY","MA","FL","GA"), each = 10),
                   Loc = rep(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"),each = 5),
                   ID = rep(c(1:10), each=2),
                   var1 = rnorm(200),
                   var2 = rnorm(200),
                   var3 = rnorm(200),
                   var4 = rnorm(200),
                   var5 = rnorm(200))
library(rstatix)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rstatix'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
UnivShapiro <- function(dat, groupvar, columns){
  var.list <- rlang::syms(names(dat[columns]))
  result<-
    dat%>%
    group_by(!!sym(groupvar))%>%
    shapiro_test(vars=var.list)%>%
    arrange(variable)%>%
    dplyr::filter(p < 0.5)
  result
}
UnivShapiro(dat1, groupvar="Region", columns=5:9)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   Region variable statistic      p
#>   <chr>  <chr>        <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 r2     var1         0.974 0.0476
#> 2 r2     var2         0.985 0.339 
#> 3 r2     var4         0.977 0.0782
#> 4 r2     var5         0.981 0.162
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This works, thanks, could you explain what the purpose of `!!sym()` is?

Comment: See this cheat sheet for tidy evaluation used in the tidyverse these days: https://psych252.github.io/psych252book/figures/cheatsheets/tidyeval.pdf. Basically, there are different ways to pass variables either as character vectors (where you use `sym`) or expressions that get evaluated in the context of the function. For !! see `?\`!!\``.